# Meaning of: Walk round with (or walk around with)

Tags: idioms

Is **walk round with** an idiom?

> So we walk round with this fear that the other person isn’t going to
> be interested in talking to us

The text is from [BBC 6 minute English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/features/6-minute-english/ep-191212). It might be a typo and be **Walk around with**. But anyway, is that an idiom?

Comment: I don't find ***walk*** particularly idiomatic here (where the ***literal*** meaning is irrelevant). I don't think there's anything unusual about, say, *He's been [**going around** with a long face](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22going+around+with+a+long+face%22) since his wife died*. But although *He's been [**walking around** with a long face](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22walking+around+with+a+long+face%22)* does actually occur, it's far less common (and at least *sometimes*, it'll be a "literal" usage).

Answer (score 1):

DailyWritingTips has a great article on this right [here](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/round-vs-around/).

From DailyWritingTips:

> One of the differences between American and British English is the usage of the words round and around. Americans use around in contexts in which most British speakers prefer round.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a typo, she clearly said "round", and it's very common in British English.

> Fans were **milling round** the hotel lobby hoping to see the film star. Meanwhile, photographers were **standing round** chatting to each other.

When you read sentences like these you know that the author is probably English or one who favours (pun intended) British English.

Answer (score 1):

No-one has answered your question 'Is that an idiom?'

*We walk [a]round with this fear* is just a way of saying *We pass our daily lives fearing that...*

It has a meaning other than the literal one, so, yes, it could be described as an idiom.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer.