# around vs round

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> I will walk around the park

vs

> I will walk round the park.

Everyone, what do you feel the difference as a native speaker?
around for me = go around the park to avoid it AND walk here and there inside the park.

round for me = walk here and there inside the park.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of: Walk round with (or walk around with)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272129/meaning-of-walk-round-with-or-walk-around-with)

Answer (score 1):

As an AmE speaker, I think both have the same meaning, and is true for your sentence.

Although "round" is more formal than "around" when describing the movement of something.

You can read more [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/getproofed.com/writing-tips/word-choice-around-vs-round/amp/).

Comment: @GreenKhan This site works because of the voting system. People give more attention to questions with more upvotes, and downvotes usually mean the question is written poorly. Unfortunately, in this case, the downvoter didn't leave a comment, which is a common courtesy here. More significant than the downvote is that there's two Close votes because your question appears to be a duplicate of a question already on the site. Other possible reasons for the downvote include not showing that you attempted to find the answer on your own before asking.

Comment: Asking questions whether others think they are repeats (which they almost 99.999999% aren't as people use different words) or other's think they are dumb questions or worded poor..is just wrong.  No one should ever be judged liked that...and this will make people hesitant and stressed out on asking questions.  Whenever my students ask me a question, I never judge them like that or they'd just give up.  IMO the more questions EVEN on the same topic is a good one as accurate and corrected EXAMPLE sentences are the best way to learn.  But what would I know, I'm just a student and a teacher. :P

Comment: @GreenKhan **I** downvoted your question, because it's a duplicate. The reason why you would think that is because you are not familiar with how this site works. You should do more research before asking. Remember, search and research!!!

Comment: I do search and research but there are rarely any good or clear answers.  Like I said, the more questions and more answers the better as people search for different things.  I also find a lot of times people use difficult or odd sentences.  This is why I like to word it the way I need to so I can understand clearer.  It's ok for you disagree, but that's how I feel and operate.  Not only do you make people worry about how they are wording their questions...or fear of repeat..they may now never ask any questions...I'm done.  Basically u stopped me from helping my students by being that way. ;)

Comment: Communications and questions is the best way to communicate until its not :P